# Error loading player. No player source found. Ubuntu 18.04 with Firefox

Tags: 18.04, video-player

I get the error message mentioned on the title when trying to watch live news video from [RT](https://www.rt.com/on-air/) 
Flash is installed on Firefox browser.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

The RT site does not need Adobe Flash Player, the use JW Player on pure JavaScript.

On my 18.04 LTS the Adobe Flash Player [test page](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) reports that I do not have Flash installed, but video is played.

Consider to try from Firefox with safe mode:

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

and if video is played normally, then your Firefox extensions/addons may be the problem.
And you will need to disable some of them (for example ad blocker or something javascript-related).

If issue persists, then you can try other browser such as Chromium (install it with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`) and try from it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Chromium and that did work so i guess I just start using that browser instead. So Chromium has nothing to do with Chrome? I just started with Ubuntu. Looks good but different than what i am used to (Mac)

Comment: Chromium is open-source variant of Google Chrome. You still can install Chrome from Google by visiting https://www.google.com/chrome/ directly if you want.